# Resetting KeyPressed() in Processing

Tags: javascript, processing, draw, keypress

I have a couple of functions in the draw method right now that are activated by key presses. Basically, there's a complex grid of squares and each square's color is filled in based upon the key the user presses ('a' makes it red, 'b' makes it green, etc), with a method assigned to each square.

However, each time the first key is pressed, it will fill in all of the squares based upon that key (for example, if the first key the user presses is 'a', all the squares will be red instead of just the first one). How do I make it so that the first key pressed only applies to the first method, the second key applies to the second method, and so on, even when it's in the looping draw() method. Here's an overly-simplified version below:

```
void draw(){
     BoxOne();
     BoxTwo();
}
void boxOne(){
     if(keyPressed){
       if(key == 'a'){
         fill(red);
       }
       if(key == 'b'){
         fill(green);
       }
       rect(10, 10, 10, 10);
     }
}
void boxTwo(){
     if(keyPressed){
       if(key == 'a'){
         fill(red);
       }
       if(key == 'b'){
         fill(green);
       }
       rect(20, 20, 10, 10);
     }
}
```

I guess, is there anyway to "reset" the keyPressed option so that it takes in another key the next time?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the function keyPressed() not the boolean global variable keyPressed. See the docs at http://processing.org/reference/keyPressed_.html.

In keyPressed() you can map the key to a particular box - I show a simple non-optimal way here where the key maps to an index that then lets you look up the params for the correct rectangle like I show. That's simple but not general or very pretty but it works.

I'd suggest avoiding repetitive code like you have in boxOne() and boxTwo() - they differ only in the box coordinates. If replaced those with a more general fillBox() that is driven by the box number.

If you only want one box showing at a time, call the background() function before calling fillBox().

```
int box = -1;
int boxParams[] = {10, 10, 10, 10
                 , 20, 20, 10, 10
                 , 30, 30, 10, 10};

void draw(){
    //background(128, 128, 128);  
    if(box >= 0) {
        fillBox(box);
    }
}

void keyPressed() {
   if(key == 'a')
       box = 0;
   else if(key == 'b')
       box = 1;
   else if(key == 'c')
       box = 2;
   else
       box = -1;
}

void fillBox(int box){
   if(key == 'a'){
     fill(255, 0, 0);
   }
   else if(key == 'b'){
     fill(0,255, 0);
   }
   else if(key == 'c'){
     fill(0,0, 255);
   }
   rect(boxParams[box * 4], boxParams[box * 4 + 1], boxParams[box * 4 + 2], boxParams[box * 4 + 3]);
}
```